# Android App Development - App crashing after launching second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-webview

I'm new to Android development and have been stuck on a issue for a few days now. Although a lot of people have got the same error answers submitted doesn't seem to help me. I have a splash screen on for 5 seconds, then launch my second activity which is just a webview. (Side note: If I don't use internet permission, second activity launches without a problem but I do get a web page not available screen, when I include the permission the app crashes after splash screen) Here are my codes;

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Thread newTimer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    newTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
                }

            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            finally
            {
                Intent nw = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(nw);
                }
            }
        };  
    newTimer.start();
   }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondlayout);

    String url = "http://ythaber.com/";
    WebView myWebWiew = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    myWebWiew.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebWiew.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebWiew.loadUrl(url);

}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.idpturkey.ythaber2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.idpturkey.ythaber2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SecondActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.idpturkey.ythaber2, PID: 18216
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.idpturkey.ythaber2/com.idpturkey.ythaber2.SecondActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class uses-permission
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
```

secondlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance,
Devrim

Comment: Thanks just remembered after submitting. Are the first few lines enough?

Comment: Please post secondlayout.xml. And yes, that's enough info from your logcat.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Edited with secondlayout.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your `secondlayout.xml`

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
```

put it in your `ManifestFile.xml` in your project.

Your all Permission should be written in your `Manifest.xml` rather than in `your_layout.xml`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried to already. But apparently I need +15 rep... I'll vote up when I have enough :)